# What are the advantages of the WPF ToolBar?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, toolbar, compare-contrast

I'm trying to decide whether I should create a simple StackPanel with Buttons on it, or whether I should use the WPF ToolBar class to contain these buttons (I am creating a simple toolbar).

What are the pros and cons to using WPF's built-in ToolBar control?

So far, these are the only advantages I have seen:

- The ToolBars can collapse when necessary; additional items are available from a context drop down.
- If the ToolBar is contained within a ToolBarTray, multiple ToolBars can be repositioned relative to each other.

Are the any other benefits to the WPF ToolBar? Neither of these apply to my simple toolbar.

Comment: Disadvantages would be the complexity. Because I'm only using a single toolbar, the repositioning grip would be unnecessary and the control would have to be retemplated to remove it.

Comment: You don't have to re-template to remove the grip; you only need to set a property. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050953/wpf-toolbar-how-to-remove-grip-and-overflow

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's the collapse button that I have retemplate to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say use the Toolbar, because you never know when the next project will come along and need it. You also never know when this project may need it. I don't think there is any real drawback to using it over a StackPanel and the advantage you didn't mention is you'll have more experiance with a built in control for the next project.

On the other hand, I don't see any harm in doing it with the StackPanel, only that if you need to extend functionallity in the future, you'll have to do some rework.

Answer (score 10):

Accessibility might be better with the WPF Toolbar, because it shows itself to Windows UI Automation as a toolbar with toolbar buttons, rather than some random controls. You never know who'll use your software.

Comment: Great answer - this never would have occurred to me.

Answer (score 4):

Another very small advantage is that buttons in the `ToolBar` will be styled correctly, whereas the buttons in the StackPanel will take on their default look. Not insurmountable by any means, but a little annoyance none-the-less.

Comment: +1.  Re-styling controls in non-native containers to look like controls in native containers is rarely worth the effort.

Comment: So the ToolBar automatically affects the styling of the buttons.

Comment: Yes, but it's possible for you to apply these styles to your own buttons or checkboxes or whatever. Look at the static members on ToolBar to see what I mean.