# WPF Toolbar with no borders

Tags: wpf, styles, toolbar

I'm trying to style the toolbar to look like a Visual Studio panel toolbar, but I can't get rid of the round corners and overflow button.

This is the code I currently have:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <DockPanel>
     <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
       ...
     </ToolBar>
  </DockPanel>
```

I've tried putting the toolbar inside a ToolBarTray and set the ToolBarTray.IsLocked to true which removed the grip, but that's it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050953/wpf-toolbar-how-to-remove-grip-and-overflow Tells how to remove the overflow button.