# Removing the little square on the bottom right of the window

Tags: wpf

I am working on this fully transparent toolbar style window that I docked on the bottom right corner of the screen. What I am unable to do is to get rid of the small square at the bottom right of the window (primarily because I don't know what it is).

[image: Transparent window]

Notice the small block at the bottom right. Any pointers regarding how to hide that thing?

My XAML (which is pretty much empty) looks like this:

```
<ui:BaseView x:Class="Infosys.DirectorySearch.UI.SearchView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Infosys.DirectorySearch.UI"
             WindowStyle="ToolWindow" 
             ResizeMode="NoResize" 
             ShowInTaskbar="False"
             WindowStartupLocation="Manual" 
             Width="400"
             Height="Auto"
             Loaded="SearchView_Loaded">    
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</ui:BaseView>
```

The glassification code is taken from here: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/aero-glass-wpf-window

Comment: What is that square anyway? But I think it's impossible to answer your question, because you seem to be using a custom base class.

Comment: The base class is nothing, but a constructor calling the function that made the window all glass. Base class is derived from the Window class.

Comment: I would suggest downloading [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and using it to find out what it is. Run it while your application is running, select your application from the list and hit Snoop, then Ctrl+Shift+Click the square in the corner. It should show you exactly what it is.

Comment: I had a similar problem with an actual WPF toolbar. The square used for overflow in the bottom right of a WPF toolbar looks similar to what you have shown. Could that be the problem you are having? If so, take a look at this related question: [WPF ToolBar: how to remove grip and overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050953/wpf-toolbar-how-to-remove-grip-and-overflow).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't you think this is a bit too much glass? It's meant to be sparingly used and never for full windows (at least as per the UX guidelines and yes, I know a certain popular browser gets that wrong).

Comment: Let's say that I really like Aero!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the solutions didn't work. But the square seems to have disappeared as I added some controls to the page. Marking this solution as answered.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution that might work for you. Make a style for your ScrollBar and set the Background to transparent.

Here is what worked for me:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">  
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```