# wpf toolbar redefine control template

Tags: wpf, xaml, toolbar, controltemplate

I am kinda new to WPF and I would like to hide the overflow arrow of my Toolbars when they don't need to be shown.
I want to create a xaml that I can use every time I have a toolbar, I am not looking for programmatical answers.
I tried following this :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa970772(v=vs.85).aspx

I created a UserControl with the root as ToolBar then tried putting the code inside  (what i understood from the msdn article) but Visual Studio says I can't put Style into ControlTemplate ('property visualtree does not support value of type style').

How should I put it in my xaml in order to work ?

I kinda want the solution of Thomas Levesque there but in xaml way, binding Visibility to IsEnabled seems like a really good way to do it
[WPF ToolBar: how to remove grip and overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050953/wpf-toolbar-how-to-remove-grip-and-overflow)

(i dont have enough reputation to comment on what he said)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could bind Visibility to the HasOverflowItems property of your toolbar and use a ValueConverter to change from Visible for True, to Hidden for False.